# Xcode not building when project lives in iCloud drive folder

Tags: xcode, icloud

I have started to use iCloud Drive to persist my files between two Macbooks I work on (`MacbookA` and `MacbookB`).  iCloud creates a clone of my Desktop on both computers that are configured with iCloud.  So on `MacbookB` I've got the path `/Users/<ME>/Desktop/Desktop - MacbookA` and `/Users/<ME>/Desktop/Desktop - MacbookB`.

I moved an Xcode project to `/Users/<ME>/Desktop/Desktop - MacbookA` and am now failing to build with the error - `/Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-ffucveeerdkfefbhdxktyzhzcsko/Build/Intermediates/.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.build/Script-BECCC6851D2428FD0068813F.sh: line 2: /Users//Desktop/Desktop: No such file or directory

I'm unable to make sense of this.  The script seems to be an Xcode script and not a custom one.  Has anyone experienced this problem?
`

Comment: Have you tried clearing the derived data?

Comment: yes.  always yes.

Comment: Have to make sure. Sorry. Does that script exist between builds? Can you examine the contents of it? Can you post the contents?

Comment: this is the script output - https://gist.github.com/alexbollbach/bdfdafd90f192a64332d1f2c3128955f

Comment: Well, line 2 of that script (the error says line 2 failed) is a cd into a directory that apparently doesn't exist. I know you're inserting placeholder for PII, but it's not clear that they are actually the identical on both machines (it's case sensitive). You can actually just paste line 2 verbatim into terminal and if it fails, that means something is wrong with the script (likely due to 2 machine interplay). I'm sorry that I don't have another Mac to take this for a spin. Hopefully someone else takes these comments to a complete answer. Best of luck.

Comment: simply dragging my Xcode project (a project root dir) from `/Users/<ME>/Desktop` to `/Users/<ME>/Desktop/Desktop` provokes this error.  So my understanding is I'm moving a generic xcode project folder from one macos dir to another.  The script is an Xcode built-in.  That is why I speculated that its an iCloud issue.

Comment: one thing in considering your most recent comment that i found confusing is that while line 2 `cd`'s into `/Users/<ME>/Desktop/Desktop - <name of host>` the error doesn't read out that full name, just `..../Desktop/Desktop`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149493/discussion-between-allen-humphreys-and-alex-bollbach).